# How to await on a cancelable subprocess without polling in Python / terminate during async.CancelledError

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I want to run a synchronous function as a subprocess from an async function in Python.

```
def subProcess():
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] subProcess running", file=sys.stderr)
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
    finally:
        print(f"[{os.getpid()}] subProcess closing", file=sys.stderr)
```

I'd like to be able to:

- await the termination of the subprocess and know the exitcode result. Ultimately I want to tell the difference between a graceful exit (including SIGTERM, SIGINTR, exitcode=0) vs. other cases, and use this to know whether not to restart a failed subprocess.
- terminate the subprocess if the coroutine that started it is cancelled. It would be nice to await the process result before returning - lets says that the subprocess serves on a port... I should wait for the old process to quit before starting a new one, otherwise the port will be unavailable.

I can't use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor=ProcessPool(), func=subProcess)`
because this doesn't give me a path to terminate the subprocess. I can't use `multiprocessing.Process` directly (I'm calling from async code).

Below is a prototype I have.

- An coroutine creates a `multiprocessing.Process` object (a non-async thing)
- A worker thread is created to `.start` and `.join` the `Process` to wait for exitcode response - when complete, it writes the exitcode (or exception) into a future
- the original coroutine waits on the future
- the coroutine may be cancelled. In my case the coroutine terminates the process (by sending a SIGINT). Because the future (which it was waiting on) was cancelled, the thread also writes its result to a second future, which the coro can wait on.

The last part is my problem:

- the process is terminated. The thread write to both futures
- the coro is waiting on the future, but `await result2` never returns or throws. Why?

Any ideas why is gets stuck on:

```
   exitcode = await result2
```

? My debug prints `runSubprocess2:thread set2`, confirmingn that result2.set_result is called.

```
import asyncio
import os
import signal
import sys
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def subProcess(*args):
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] subProcess{args} running", file=sys.stderr)
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
    finally:
        print(f"[{os.getpid()}] subProcess{args} done", file=sys.stderr)



MISSING = object()

async def runSubprocess2(target=subProcess, args=(), name=None):

    def task():
        # Sync code to start, join the Process and write the 
        # exitcode/exception to the outer cooroutine's futures.
        # This all works as expected. Both result2 is assigned to
        # (result1 was cancelled already)
        p.start()
        r = None
        try:
            p.join()
            r = p.exitcode
            if 1:
                print(f"runSubprocess2:thread set2")
                result2.set_result(r)
                if not result1.cancelled():
                    print(f"runSubprocess2:thread set1")
                    result1.set_result(r)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(f"runSubprocess2:thread exception {type(e)}")
            if not result2.cancelled():
                result2.set_exception(e)
                print("runSubprocess2:thread result2 set ex")
            if not result1.cancelled():
                result1.set_exception(e)
                print("runSubprocess2:thread result1 set ex")
            else:
                print("runSubprocess2:thread  terminated")
            print(f"runSubprocess2:thread exception OK")

        finally:
           print(f"runSubprocess2:thread terminated (exitcode={r})")

    result1 = asyncio.Future()
    result2 = asyncio.Future()  # Used if result1 is cancelled
    p = Process(target=target,
                args=args,
                daemon=True,
                name=name)
    threading.Thread(
        target=task,
        daemon=True,
        name=name
    ).start()

    # task = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(ProcessPoolExecutor(), subProcess)
    exitcode = MISSING
    try:
        exitcode = await result1
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print(f"runSubprocess2:coro cancelled {type(e)}")
    except BaseException as e:
        print(f"runSubprocess2:coro exception {type(e)}")
        raise
    finally:
        # If the process was not killed, send a KeyboardInterrupt
        wait = not result1.done()
        if result1.cancelled():
            # This path is visited in this example:
            wait = True
            print(f"runSubprocess2:coro send {p.pid} terminate ...")
            # p.terminate()
            os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
            print("runSubprocess2:coro sent SIGINT ... OK")

        if wait:
            print(f"runSubprocess2:coro awaiting shutdown ... {result2}")
            try:
                print(f"runSubprocess2:coro awaiting 2")
                exitcode = await result2   #  <<< STUCK HERE. What the hey!
                print(f"runSubprocess2:coro awaiting shutdown ... OK exitcode={exitcode}")
            except BaseException as e:
                print(f"runSubprocess2:coro awaiting shutdown ... {type(e)}")   # ???
                raise
            finally:
                print(f"runSubprocess2:coro awaiting shutdown ... DONE {result2}")

        else:
            print("runSubprocess2:coro terminated")

    assert exitcode is not MISSING
    # Handle exit code cases here.





async def main():
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] main", file=sys.stderr)


    if 1:

        nTasks = 1
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(runSubprocess2(target=subProcess, args=(i,)))  #asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor=None, func=runSubprocess2)
                 for i in range(nTasks)]

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Cancelling...")
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
        print("Cancelling... OK")
        try:
            await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)

    print("Done", file=sys.stderr)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    def _main():
        try:
            asyncio.run(main())
        finally:
            print(f"Main exit.")
```

Tested on py3.8, 3.11

Comment: An asyncio.Future is not threadsafe.  You can't create a Future in one thread and set its result in another thread, as your function task is doing.  You should use  asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to make sure all access to Futures are done in the correct thread.

Comment: Thanks -- but I'm confused. The thread task that joins the process is non-async, and can't be run with run_coroutine_threadsafe.
For the coroutine runSubprocess2, the result is the same when it is run with run_coroutine_threadsafe.

Comment: It seem like I should be able to switch out asyncio.Future() with a threadsafe object. Is there no such class?

Comment: Oh -- use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe from the thread for setting the futures. Got it!